# Use sed command with variables

Tags: shell-script, sed, quoting, variable-substitution

I have tried every possible solution available on the Stack Overflow and its related websites but did not find any solution. I spent a reasonable amount of time on this issue and am finally posting this question.

I want to use the `sed` command with shell variables. My script is pretty simple:

```
## string to replace is the text after comma in the variable pc.
to_replace=${pc#*,}
echo $to_replace

##text to be replaced by the following line
replace_with="PARTITIONED BY ($pc1);"
echo $replace_with

## use sed command to replace.
sed "s@$to_replace@$replace_with@" $entry  ## $entry is the variable that contains the file name
```

The two `echo` commands give the following outputs respectively:

```
PARTITIONEDED BY (date_key );  ## the text I want to be replaced
PARTITIONED BY ( date_key int );  ## the text I want to replace with
```

I either get an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command
```

or the text does not get replaced at all.

Someone please help. I am using Centos 6 (if that matters). Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_or_ the text does not get replaced at all"? When do you get an error and when don't you get an error?

Comment: What is your shell? This is pretty sure no `sed` issue, but strange things happening du to shell magic. Maybe the output of `echo "s@$to_replace@$replace_with@"` can reveil what script `sed` has to deal with.

Comment: @Philippos The output for that instruction is `sed s@ PARTITIONEDEDED BY (date_key );@PARTITIONED BY ( date_key int );@@ <file_name>`

Comment: @kskp Ok, so where does that extra `@` at the end come from?

Comment: I just tried that because even one @ was not working. I tried every possible way of this command. :(

Comment: replacing '@' as separator by good old '/' won't do ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. On my Arch, `echo "PARTITIONEDED BY (date_key );" | sed "s@$to_replace@$replace_with@"` works as expected. Does that work for you? What file name are you trying it with? Can you break this down into the most minimal example that reproduces the problem? Something we can copy directly and try.

Comment: The same works in mine too. In fact, I do a "cat <file_name> | sed "s@$to_replace@$replace_with@" and it works. I don't know why it doesn't work when I put the same instructions in the script. This is weird. I am using bash. I put the same command in the script, I get that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command
```

The error message says the error happens on the second character, which seems curious. I can reproduce this by putting a newline in the start of the first variable:

```
$ a=$'\nfoo'
$ b='bar'
$ sed "s@$a@$b@"
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command
```

An unescaped newline terminates the sed command. Putting the newline later in `a` would of course give the error on a later character.

You did print out both variables earlier in the script, but they weren't quoted, so any leading whitespace in them would have been be removed, and whitespace in the middle would display as single spaces.

Check what your variables actually contain, with something like these:

```
printf ">%s<\n" "$to_replace"
printf "%q\n" "$to_replace"
```

The latter is a Bash feature that displays the string quoted in a way that Bash accepts as input. `set -x` would also show what goes to sed's command line, but you'd need to notice the literal newline from its output.

So, if a single leading newline is all there is, you could remove it
in the beginning of the script:

```
to_replace=${pc#*,}
to_replace=${to_replace#$'\n'}
```

(You could combine those into one, but separate steps work even if the newline isn't there.)

Comment: Absolutely understand what you are saying. Thank you so much! The output for the 2 printf statements are: `PARTITIONEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDED BY (date_key );<
$'\nPARTITIONEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDED BY (date_key );'`

Please suggest what to do in this case.

Comment: @kskp, well, there it is, the `$'\n...'`. The first `printf` I gave prints a literal newline, and they don't really work the comments here. Edited for one way to get rid of it. (It gets somewhat messier if you may have more whitespace in the variable, I won't go into that here.)

Comment: See also [How to ensure that string interpolated into \`sed\` substitution escapes all metachars](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059)

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
sed -i -e "s@$to_replace@$replace_with@g" "$entry"
```

where

- `-i` means replace "in place", If you don't use `-i` replace will be on standard output.

Comment: I get this error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: That's just the same sed command the OP already tried with an added `-i`. If the command fails, the `-i` won't make any difference.